# JSZip VUE how to resolve a promise array and save to local variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, promise, jszip

Haven't worked with async functions so i'm kind of lost here...
What I'm trying to accomplish is to iterate through files in folder that is within a zip file with JSZip, save these files in an array and then sort them, save them to a local variable so I can send them further.

Here is my code where I get an array of promises:

```
async extractTests(file){
  let Zip = new JSZip();
  let tests = await Zip.loadAsync(file).then((zip) => {
      const promises = [];
      zip.folder("tests").forEach(async function (relativePath, file) {
        promises.push({ name: relativePath, data: await zip.file("tests/" + relativePath).async("text") });
      });
      return promises;
    })
  return tests;
}
```

Then I'm trying to sort the array in the event function which runs when a zip file is added:

```
extract(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  let res = this.extractTests(file);
  res.then(function (r) {
    res.sort(function (a, b) {
      var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
      var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
      console.log(a.name);
      if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
      }
      else {
        return 1;
      }
    });
  })
}
```

The list needs to be sorted because it gets resolved in the wrong order - as far as I've gathered is that the sort function doesn't even fire - pretty sure it's something to do with a asynchronous function.
The sort would work on local variable and it would be much simpler for me to save the array as a local variable - so how could I do that and resolve the promises.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In `extract()`, `res.sort` should be `r.sort` (`res` is a `Promise`, and `r` is the resolved `Promise[]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `async` / `await` on higher-order function is highly discouraged and may lead un-predictable behavior where your code may seem to work but actually only triggers some asynchronous calls without providing the desired output.

I cannot reproduce the issue for sure without having the archive structure with the same library, but you can try to change your extraction function as follows:

```
async function extractTests(file: any) {
  let Zip = new JSZip();
  let tests = await Zip.loadAsync(file)
    .then((zip) => {
      const promises = [];
      zip.folder("tests")
        .forEach(function (relativePath, file) { // removed async function
          promises.push(
            zip.file("tests/" + relativePath)
              .async("text")
              .then((data) => { // replaced with Promise fulfillment data update
                return { name: relativePath, data: data }
              })
          );
        });
      return promises;
    })
  return Promise.all(tests); // Resolve all promises in parallel
}
```